# Xamarin Forms, keyboard closing on Entry after every key stroke

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

In some Entry fields the keyboard is closing on every key stroke. This problem was introduced since Xamarin Forms 3.0. So in 2.5 this problem didn't occur.

This problem only occurs in iOS, not Android (afaik).

You can reproduce it with this test code:

Page.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestEntryKeyboard" x:Class="TestEntryKeyboard.MainPage">
    <StackLayout x:Name="stackTest">
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Page.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var table = new TableView()
        {
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            Intent = TableIntent.Form,
            HasUnevenRows = true,
            Root = new TableRoot()
        };

        stackTest.Children.Clear();
        stackTest.Children.Add(table);

        TableSection section = new TableSection("");
        table.Root.Add(section);

        for (int index = 1; index < 20; index++)
        {
            var viewCell = new ViewCell();
            var stack = new StackLayout();
            viewCell.View = stack;

            var label = new Label() { Text = $"Entry {index}:" };
            stack.Children.Add(label);

            var entry = new Entry() { };
            stack.Children.Add(entry);

            section.Add(viewCell);
        }

    }
}
```

On an iPhone SE screen size, the problem occurs in entry field number 10 and 11, at least in my test scenario. If you use an other iPhone with a larger screen size, like XR, the problem occurs in other Entry fields, like for example 15 and 16.

So if you test this, be sure to test in multiple Entry controls, because many will work and only a couple of them not.

My guess is that it has something to do with cell reusing.

NB: The test code I published here is all I use. So I don't use event handlers.

Comment: Did you do something other in the view .Such as add touchevent on the view.I use your code and it works fine.

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT Which version of XF do you use. Please know that the problem only occurs from XF 3.0, in iOS and only on some entry fields, depending on the screen size. So for example: field 1 to 9 may work ok, but other fields might not. Also the test code I published here is all I use; no event handlers.

Comment: I test all entry .I used the xamarin.forms 3.x

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT Which iOS version did you use? Device or emulator? Which iPhone?

Comment: I use iphone se 11.1 and 12.1;iPhone X 12.0